# jquery use next and each to change the url of the elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have four links which points to four pages

```
<a href="asdf">asdf</a>
<a href="asdfer">1244</a>
<a href="iuiuy">qwer</a>
<a href="asdfasdf">asdfqew</a>
```

i just want to add number from current url to the href of the next elements based on the current page url argument

(ie) 
   if i am at page "asdf" then the other three links needs to add sum number

```
 <a href="asdf">asdf</a>
<a href="asdfer/123">1244</a>
<a href="iuiuy/123">qwer</a>
<a href="asdfasdf/123">asdfqew</a>
```

here is the code i used

```
 var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var split = pathname.split("/")[4];
 console.log(jQuery("#pagetabs li a").each().next().attr('href')); 
if(split.match(/^\d+$/)){
  jQuery("#pagetabs li a").each(function(){
      href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
      newhref = href+'/'+ split;  
       jQuery(this).next().attr('href',newhref); 
  });

}
```

but this is the error i am getting

```
TypeError: a is undefined
http://example.com/misc/jquery.js?4
Line 12
```

is anything wrong with my code

Comment: what is the purpose of this line `jQuery(this).next().attr('href');`. I see that it's useless

Comment: You would need to provide full code so we can see what exactly is going on as line 12 is not actually in your provided JQuery. 

Also what are the "some numbers" you need adding? are they just random?

Comment: some or sum, they are different?

Comment: The `.each` is already iterating over the entire array of links. You don't need to use `.next` and, worse, that is causing the code to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HQx88/1/)**

```
var split = 1563; // number from current url 
if(split){
  $("#pagetabs li a").each(function(index){
      var $this=$(this); 
      if(index!=0)
      $(this).attr('href',$this.attr('href')+'/'+ split)
    });

}
```

Comment: The problem here is that it changes the link of the first element as well. It should change the links of all but not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I think that .each method goes though all your links. But once it reaches the last one, you say .next() which means "go to the next link". And there is no links anymore. So, instead of each I'll suggest to use for loop:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var split = pathname.split("/")[4]; // number from current url 
if(split.match(/^\d+$/)){
    var links = jQuery("#pagetabs li a");
    for(var i=1; i<links.length; i++) {
        var link = links.eq(i);
        link.attr("href", link.attr("href") + "/" + split);
    }
}
```